# LRU cache implementation idea

Tags: java, caching

I am trying to implement lru cache in Java.
My idea is:

- Store in linkedList the order of the cache elements.
- Store in hashMap the elements appear in the list for relatively fast check.

I struggle to implement the part of moving element to the begining of the cache.
My idea was to map each element from the cache to the specific element iterator, and that way the element removal will take O(1) time instead of serching for the element in the list, but because my list is changing constantly the iterator is useless (you can only use it after I finish all manipulation on the list).

I heard that the kind of implementation is possible in C & C++, is there any way to implement the above idea in Java?

Can any of you suggest a way to implement the above (without using others data structures like LinkedHashMap, only linkedList and regular hashMap)?

This is the code so far - assume `bookId` is what I'm caching.

The operation that fails are all `iterator.next()` after changing the list.

```
private HashMap<String, ListIterator> fromBookNameToIteraot = new HashMap<>();
    private LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private HashMap<Integer, String> fromBookIdToBookName = new HashMap<>();
    private Iterator<Integer> iterator = queue.listIterator(0);
    private static int bookObjectID = 0;
    private int cacheSize;
    //Ctor
    public LRUCache(int cacheSize) {
        this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
    }

    public void access(String i_BookName){
        int tempBook = 0;
        //In case the requested book in cache (in our map) - O(1) remove operation
        if (fromBookNameToIteraot.containsKey(i_BookName)){
            iterator = fromBookNameToIteraot.get(i_BookName);
            //Validate the queue is not empty, then remove the one from the map
            if(iterator.hasNext()){
                tempBook = iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
            }
            queue.addFirst(tempBook);
            iterator = queue.listIterator(0);
            fromBookNameToIteraot.put(i_BookName, (ListIterator) iterator);
            return;
        }
        /*
        *In this case the book is not in cache, and the cache is full
        * - get the last book element from queue as least recently used, and remove it.
        * - get the book name (since i don't have DB i used another map to fetch bookName from book object.
        * - delete the book from the cache map.
        * - insert the new book to cache
        * */
        else if(queue.size() == cacheSize) {
            int bookToDel = queue.getLast();
            queue.removeLast();
            String bookNameToDel = fromBookIdToBookName.get(bookToDel);
            fromBookNameToIteraot.remove(bookNameToDel);
            fromBookIdToBookName.remove(bookToDel);
        }

        queue.addFirst(bookObjectID);
        iterator = queue.listIterator(0);
        fromBookNameToIteraot.put(i_BookName, (ListIterator) iterator);
        fromBookIdToBookName.put(bookObjectID, i_BookName);
        bookObjectID++;
    }
```

Comment: You should really post some code for people to be able to help :-) I'll take a blind shot and tell you your map should contain the list nodes instead of values

Comment: You should read the code for `LinkedHashMap` or Apache's `LruMap`. You do not need to use their code, but can use them as a guide to understand how they solve it. They map the key to a doubly-linked list node, which holds the value and the list pointers. This lets them remove in O(1), and offer onto the tail (MRU) or poll from the head (LRU).